# <rejected> TypeError: promisify is not a function

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose, promise, es6-promise

**Can anyone let me know the solution of my problem. I got an error again and again whenever i run this setup. i checked a lot but i didn't get that. please look on my code files and tell me the solution.whenever 
 i send some data through the form page then, this error will show, sometimes i think, is it the problem of modern ecmascript or not**.

```
start.js

const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const dotenv = require('dotenv');

// import environmental variables from our variables.env file
require('dotenv').config({ path: 'variable.env' });



// Connect to our Database and handle any bad connections
mongoose.connect(process.env.DATABASE, { useNewUrlParser: true });
mongoose.set('useCreateIndex', true);
mongoose.Promise = global.Promise; // Tell Mongoose to use ES6 promises
mongoose.connection.on('error', (err) => {
  console.error(`sir your error → ${err.message}`);
});

process.on('unhandledRejection', function(reason, promise) {
  console.log(promise);
});

require('./models/User');

// READY?! Let's go!


// Start our app!
const app = require('./app');
app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 7777);
const server = app.listen(app.get('port'), () => {
  console.log(`Express running → PORT ${server.address().port}`);
});
```

```
userController.js


const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const User = mongoose.model('User');
const promisify = require('es6-promisify');

exports.loginForm = (req, res) => {
  res.render('login', { title: 'Login' })
};

exports.registerForm = (req, res) => {
  res.render('register', { title: 'Register' })
};

  exports.validateRegister = (req, res, next) => {
  req.sanitizeBody('user2');
  req.checkBody('user2', 'You must supply a name!').notEmpty();
  req.checkBody('user9', 'That Email is not valid!').isEmail();
  req.sanitizeBody('user9').normalizeEmail({
    gmail_remove_dots: false,
    remove_extension: false,
    gmail_remove_subaddress: false
  });
  req.checkBody('password', 'Password Cannot be Blank!').notEmpty();
  req.checkBody('confirmPassword', 'Confirmed Password cannot be blank!').notEmpty();
  req.checkBody('confirmPassword', 'Oops! Your passwords do not match').equals(req.body.password);

  const errors = req.validationErrors();
  if (errors) {
    req.flash('error', errors.map(err => err.msg));
    res.render('register');
    return; // stop the fn from running
  }
  next(); // there were no errors!
};


exports.register = async (req, res, next) => {
    const user = new User({ 

      Representing: req.body.user1,
      Name:req.body.user2,
      companyName:req.body.user3,
      companyNumber:req.body.user4,
      userAddress:req.body.user5,
      companyAddress:req.body.user6,
      activePhone:req.body.user7,
      companyPhone:req.body.user8,
      activeEmail:req.body.user9,
      companyEmail:req.body.user10,
      Aadhar:req.body.user11,
      Pan:req.body.user12,
      Term1:req.body.userTerm1,
      Term2:req.body.userTerm2
  });

    const register = promisify(User.register, User);
    await register(user, req.body.password);
    res.send("all has been saved")
    next(); // pass to authController.login
  };
```

```
User.js


const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;
mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
const md5 = require('md5');
const validator = require('validator');
const mongooseErrorHandler = require('mongoose-mongodb-errors');
const passportLocalMongoose = require('passport-local-mongoose');

const userSchema = new Schema({
    Representing: {
        type: String,
        required: 'Please enter your representing',
        trim: true,
        unique:true
    },

    Name:{
        type: String,
        required: 'Please enter your Name',
        trim: true,
        unique:true
    },
    companyName:{
        type: String,
        required: 'Please enter your  Institute Name',
        trim: true,
        unique:true
    },
    companyNumber:{
        type: Number,
        required: 'Please enter your  Institute Number',
        trim: true,
        unique:true
    },
    userAddress:{
        type: String,
        required: 'Please enter your Address',
        trim: true,
        unique:true
    },
    companyAddress:{
        type: String,
        required: 'Please enter your Institute Address',
        trim: true,
        unique:true
    },
    activePhone:{
        type: Number,
        required: 'Please enter your active number',
        trim: true,
        unique:true
    },
    companyPhone:{
        type: Number,
        required: 'Please enter your institute phone number',
        trim: true,
        unique:true
    },
    activeEmail:{
        type: String,
        lowercase: true,
        unique: true,
        trim: true,
        validate:[validator.isEmail,'Invalid Email Address'],
        trim: true
    },
     companyEmail:{
        type: String,
        lowercase: true,
        unique: true,
        trim: true,
        validate:[validator.isEmail,'Invalid Email Address'],
        required: 'Please enter your institute phone number',
        trim: true
    },

    Aadhar:{
        type: Number,
        required: 'Please enter your institute phone number',
        trim: true,
        unique:true
    },
    Pan:{
        type: Number,
        required: 'Please enter your institute phone number',
        trim: true,
        unique:true
    },
    Term1:{
         type: [String]
    },
    Term2:{
        type: [String]
    }

})

userSchema.plugin(passportLocalMongoose, {usernameField: 'user9'});
userSchema.plugin(mongooseErrorHandler);

module.exports = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);
```

```
start.js


const express = require('express')
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const session = require('express-session');
const expressValidator = require('express-validator');
const MongoStore = require('connect-mongo')(session);
const path = require('path');
const passport = require('passport');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const flash = require('connect-flash');
const routes = require('./routes/index');
const errorHandlers = require('./handlers/errorHandlers');

const app = express();

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname + '/views')));
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
//app.engine('html', require('ejs').renderFile);
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');



app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

app.use(expressValidator());

// populates req.cookies with any cookies that came along with the request
//app.use(cookieParser());


app.use(session({
  secret: process.env.SECRET,
  key: process.env.KEY,
  resave: false,
  saveUninitialized: false,
  store: new MongoStore({ mongooseConnection: mongoose.connection })
}));

app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());


app.use(flash());

app.use((req, res, next) => {
  res.locals.flashes = req.flash();
  next();
});


// After allllll that above middleware, we finally handle our own routes!
app.use('/', routes);


// If that above routes didnt work, we 404 them and forward to error handler
app.use(errorHandlers.notFound);

// One of our error handlers will see if these errors are just validation errors
//app.use(errorHandlers.flashValidationErrors);

// Otherwise this was a really bad error we didn't expect! Shoot eh
//if (app.get('env') === 'development') {
  /* Development Error Handler - Prints stack trace */
  //app.use(errorHandlers.developmentErrors);
//}

// production error handler
//app.use(errorHandlers.productionErrors);

// done! we export it so we can start the site in start.js
module.exports = app;
```

```
package.json

{
  "name": "user-login",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "a little login or sign up page",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "nodemon start.js"
  },
  "keywords": [
    "prateek"
  ],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "connect-flash": "^0.1.1",
    "connect-mongo": "^2.0.3",
    "dotenv": "^8.0.0",
    "ejs": "^2.6.1",
    "es6-promisify": "^6.0.1",
    "express": "^4.17.0",
    "express-session": "^1.16.1",
    "express-validator": "^5.3.1",
    "md5": "^2.2.1",
    "mongoose": "^5.5.11",
    "mongoose-mongodb-errors": "0.0.2",
    "nodemon": "^1.19.0",
    "passport": "^0.4.0",
    "passport-local": "^1.0.0",
    "passport-local-mongoose": "^5.0.1",
    "path": "^0.12.7",
    "validator": "^11.0.0"
  }
}
```

```
error

 <rejected> TypeError: promisify is not a function
      at exports.register (C:\Users\Kulfi\Desktop\user-login\controllers\userController.js:55:22)
      at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\Kulfi\Desktop\user-login\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
      at next (C:\Users\Kulfi\Desktop\user-login\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:137:13)
      at Route.dispatch (C:\Users\Kulfi\Desktop\user-login\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:112:3)
      at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\Kulfi\Desktop\user-login\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
      at C:\Users\Kulfi\Desktop\user-login\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:281:22
      at Function.process_params (C:\Users\Kulfi\Desktop\user-login\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:335:12)
      at next (C:\Users\Kulfi\Desktop\user-login\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:275:10)
      at Function.handle (C:\Users\Kulfi\Desktop\user-login\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:174:3)
      at router (C:\Users\Kulfi\Desktop\user-login\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:47:12)
      at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\Kulfi\Desktop\user-login\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
      at trim_prefix (C:\Users\Kulfi\Desktop\user-login\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:317:13)
      at C:\Users\Kulfi\Desktop\user-login\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:284:7
      at Function.process_params (C:\Users\Kulfi\Desktop\user-login\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:335:12)
      at next (C:\Users\Kulfi\Desktop\user-login\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:275:10)
      at app.use (C:\Users\Kulfi\Desktop\user-login\app.js:47:3) }
```

Comment: Which version of node you are using?

Comment: I am using 11.13.0 version @curious_coder

Answer (score 1):

In userController.js, change this:

```
const promisify = require("es6-promisify");
```

to this:

```
const { promisify } = require("es6-promisify");
```

Another option if you do not want to use object destructuring is this:

```
const promisify = require("es6-promisify").promisify;
```

You need to require es6-promisify this way because the package [currently exports the promisify function inside of an object](https://github.com/digitaldesignlabs/es6-promisify/blob/7fc27d787d3b4ab58111ffbf874356eb411a0790/lib/promisify.js#L69) instead of exporting the function directly.

Comment: Sorry Sir,  error is still showing but at this time error is "Right-hand side of 'instanceof' is not callable"

Comment: I believe this fixed the error in your question.  You may have other problems in your code that need to be fixed before the program will run without error.  I suggest posting a new question with the new error you are experiencing to keep this question focused on the promisify error.

Answer (score 0):

If you have error:

> Right-hand side of 'instanceof' is not callable

You can try:

```
exports.register = async (req, res, next) => {
    const newUser = new User({ email: req.body.email, name: req.body.name })
    await User.register(newUser, req.body.password);
    next()
  }
```